# DOMO - MySQL unpivoting tables and creating unique sequential number for each row

Tags: mysql, database, unpivot, domo

I want to be able to unpivot tables that I currently have. I always forget that DOMO doesn't allow certain functionatlieis. with the code provided below, how can i translate this to DOMO mysql?

Code Starts here:

select o.*, isnull(c.Qty,0) as CancelQty, isnull(s.Qty,0) as ShipQty
from
(
-- ORDERED --
SELECT ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SUM(Qty)  AS Qty, SizeLookupCol
FROM
(
select  ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_STYP, ORS_CHGN, Size, Qty, SizeLookupCol = SUBSTRING(SIZE,7,2)
from    `oropns_open_order_size_detail`
unpivot (Qty for  Size in (ORS_OR1,ORS_OR2,ORS_OR3,ORS_OR4,ORS_OR5,ORS_OR6,ORS_OR7,ORS_OR8,ORS_OR9,ORS_OR10,ORS_OR11,ORS_OR12,ORS_OR13,ORS_OR14,ORS_OR15,ORS_OR16,ORS_OR17,ORS_OR18)) as A
) a
GROUP BY ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SizeLookupCol
HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0
) o
left join
(
-- CANCELLED --
SELECT ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SUM(Qty) AS Qty, SizeLookupCol
FROM
(
select  ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_STYP, ORS_CHGN, Size, Qty, SizeLookupCol = SUBSTRING(SIZE,7,2)
from    `oropns_open_order_size_detail`
unpivot (Qty for Size in (ORS_CN1,ORS_CN2,ORS_CN3,ORS_CN4,ORS_CN5,ORS_CN6,ORS_CN7,ORS_CN8,ORS_CN9,ORS_CN10,ORS_CN11,ORS_CN12,ORS_CN13,ORS_CN14,ORS_CN15,ORS_CN16,ORS_CN17,ORS_CN18)) as A
) a
GROUP BY ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SizeLookupCol
HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0
) c
    on o.ORS_ORDN = c.ORS_ORDN and o.ORS_LINE = c.ORS_LINE and o.SizeLookupCol = c.SizeLookupCol
left join
(
-- SHIPPED --
SELECT ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SUM(Qty)  AS Qty, SizeLookupCol
FROM
(
select  ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, Qty, SizeLookupCol = SUBSTRING(SIZE,7,2)
from    `oropns_open_order_size_detail`
unpivot (Qty for Size in (ORS_SH1,ORS_SH2,ORS_SH3,ORS_SH4,ORS_SH5,ORS_SH6,ORS_SH7,ORS_SH8,ORS_SH9,ORS_SH10,ORS_SH11,ORS_SH12,ORS_SH13,ORS_SH14,ORS_SH15,ORS_SH16,ORS_SH17,ORS_SH18)) as A
) a
GROUP BY ORS_ORDN, ORS_LINE, ORS_CHGN, Size, SizeLookupCol
HAVING SUM(Qty) > 0
) s
    on o.ORS_ORDN = s.ORS_ORDN and o.ORS_LINE = s.ORS_LINE and o.SizeLookupCol = s.SizeLookupCol

Result: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Created a new table to unpivot columns and assign new index as a unique identifier